# Sum two columns to a third one of DataGridView. How?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

How can I sum the values of two dataGridView columns and store the result in a third column for each row ?

Comment: Hi, please show some code on how you load the data from the database and how you bind it to the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Do what ever the calculations you want in the dataSource and bind it after calculating values.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you get the data for the Grid? from a datatable? If yes, you can add another column to the datatable and set the "Expression" property of the newly created datatablecolumn to the sum of other two columns that you already have. You might want to do the following:

```
<yourDataTable>.Columns.Add("yourNewSumColumnName");
<yourDataTable.Columns["yourSumColumnName"].Expression = "<yourExistingCol1> +  <yourExistingCol2>"
```

Comment: This works but if <yourExistingCol1> looks like <your Existing Col1> you need to put it in [] [your Existing Col1]

Answer (score 0):

```
<yourDataTable>.Columns.Add("yourNewSumColumnName");
<yourDataTable.Columns["yourSumColumnName"].Expression = "<yourExistingCol1> +  <yourExistingCol2>"
```

Comment: @ Arun : I think you should manage only one answer per question.

Comment: @Charith, my second answer contains actual code - which could not fit in my first response.

Comment: @ChrisWue: Thank you Chris, I am not sure if this has got anything with my "previlege" (600 character limit?) - when I attempted to post my first response, it did not show my code in the preview pane. Thank you for the edit. That is precisely how I would have wanted.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't given any code I am going to assume you are putting data straight into the DataGridView. As @Arun suggests below the calculations should be done in the underlying data layer then bind that to the DataGridView with a 'Binding Source'.

Are you using SQL? If so;

```
Select (Order.qty) as Quantity , (Product.Price) as Price,(Order.qty * Product.price) as             total from Order 
Inner Join Product on Order.Pid = Product.PID
```

Otherwise here are some useful links I found, sorry I don't have time to copy and paste in some content from these websites;

[A GridView Control with Subtotals](http://aspguy.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/a-gridview-control-with-subtotals/)

[DataTable.Compute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)